# Nginx Rewrite - Last Ignored?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In Apache, this logic works fine - and according to documentation, with Nginx too.

```
location = /login/ {    rewrite ^(.*)$ /login.php last; }
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?c=$1 last;
```

Ideally, domain.com/login/ would direct to login.php

Anything else would direct to page.php, and pass along the details.
However, instead - all requests are directed to page.php

Is something missing? :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have wrong assumption that order of directives matters, but actually it does not. Nginx has strict order of directives execution and “server-level” `rewrite` works before it tries to match `location`.

You should avoid “server-level” `rewrite`s. In this case I would write:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?c=$1;
}

location = /login/ {
    rewrite ^ /login.php;
}

# I guess you have something like this too
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oc order matters. But some directives are evaluated first. Rewrite trigger the reevaluation of the location blocks. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: @quazardous generally order doesn't matter. There are exceptions and directives from rewrite module are most common. Second most common is regexp `location`s.